# Fragment / ViewPager in FragmentPagerAdapter not updating its View

Tags: android, view

I have a FragmentPagerAdapter which holds several Fragments. The content of these Fragments change, but I did not get the Fragment to update in my update function.
I already tried these suggestions without luck:

[ViewPager PagerAdapter not updating the View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263291/viewpager-pageradapter-not-updating-the-view)

[Android force Fragment to rebuild View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7796952/android-force-fragment-to-rebuild-view)

Here is a sniped of my code:

```
private void updateNavigation() {
//update code to redraw the fragment
//not workind
//mNavigationViewPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        AFragment newFragment = new AFragment();
        args.putString("test");
        newFragment.setArguments(args);

        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.navigation_pager, newFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
```

and this is the fragment:

```
public static class AFragment extends Fragment {
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment, draw layout dynamically
            MyLinearLayout fl = new MyLinearLayout(getActivity());
                    Button btn = new Button(getActivity());
                    btn.setText(String.valueOf(cnt++));   
                    btn.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
                    btn.setPadding(28, 7, 0, 0);
                    fl.addView(btn, new MyLinearLayout.LayoutParams(7, 5, 70, 50));
                    fl.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
            }
            return fl;
        }
    }
```

activity on create:
(..)

```
 mNavigationViewPager = new ViewPager(this);
            mNavigationViewPager.setId(R.id.navigation_pager);
            mTabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(this, mNavigationViewPager);
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("text1"),
                    fragmentNr1, null);
 actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
```

When I call

```
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
```

an an options menu interaction and afterwards do

```
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
```

in another options menu, the fragments gets updated correct.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ViewPager PagerAdapter not updating the View](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263291/viewpager-pageradapter-not-updating-the-view)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working, I just made a typo.