# Replace a fragment which has been added as tab of a tabhost

Tags: android, user-interface

I got the following problem with my android app:

I have a TabHost containing some Fragments as Tabs. These Fragments have been added programmatically. Now I would like to replace the content of a tab with an other Fragment.
And I don't know how to achieve that. I [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7796952/android-force-fragment-to-rebuild-view) how to replace a fragment which was added via xml, but that is not what I'm trying to achieve.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

EDIT: the requested source (only the relevant parts, if more is needed please tell me)

I have a method to initialize the tabhost and add the tabs/fragments programmatically:

```
private void initialiseTabHost(Bundle args) {
    mTabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup();

    addUserListTab(args);
    //methods to add other tabs


    mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
}

private void addUserListTab(Bundle args){
    TabInfo tabInfo = null;
    LayoutParams tabIconParams = new LayoutParams(200, 110);
    tabIconParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
    View userIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator,mTabHost, false);
    ImageView userIcon = (ImageView) userIndicator.findViewById(R.id.tab_icon);  
    userIcon.setLayoutParams(tabIconParams);
    TabSpec specUser = mTabHost.newTabSpec("user");
    specUser.setIndicator(userIndicator);
    userIcon.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.selector_user));
    userIcon.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);

    AddTab(this, this.mTabHost, specUser, ( tabInfo = new TabInfo("user", ListUserFragment.class, args)));
    this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);

}
private static void AddTab(MainActivity activity, TabHost tabHost, TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec, TabInfo tabInfo) {
    // Attach a Tab view factory to the spec
    tabSpec.setContent(activity.new TabFactory(activity));
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
}
```

The Problem is that I don't understand how I can replace the ListUserFragment which I added programmatically to the tabhost. When I pass the container of the tabhost how can I specify which tab of the currently four should contain the new fragment and of course the old should be removed/hidden.

Comment: nice answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18120510/dynamically-changing-the-fragments-inside-a-fragment-tab-host/19859871#19859871

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the `FragmentManager` and begin a `FragmentTransaction` to replace the current `Fragment` with another one.

```
 getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new Fragment()).commit();
```

Be sure to also read the official [fragment guide.](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).

Comment: This does not seem to work for replacing fragments which are added programmatically. The R.id. container describes the container of the old fragment which I do not have since I added the fragment and it's parent a TabHost programmatically.

Comment: This works, for every kind of fragment. Post me the source of your project.

Comment: I provided the relevant parts of my source in my EDIT. If any more is needed please tell me. I hope that this enough to illustrate my problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: what id should be used when replace the fragment in this case "soriak"?